# How can I fix "NullabilityInfoContext is not supported in the current application" on a .Net MAUI iOS app using EFCore and SQLite?

Tags: ios, sqlite, entity-framework-core, maui

I have a project which uses .Net MAUI, Entity Framework Core and SQLite. I am targetting Android and iOS.

When I deploy to Android, the app works fine. However, when deploying to iOS (in Debug mode, directly from VS2022), upon starting the app, it crashes with the following error:

> An error occurred: 'NullabilityInfoContext is not supported in the current application because 'System.Reflection.NullabilityInfoContext.IsSupported' is set to false. Set the MSBuild Property 'NullabilityInfoContextSupport' to true in order to enable it.'. Callstack: '   at System.Reflection.NullabilityInfoContext.EnsureIsSupported()
> at System.Reflection.NullabilityInfoContext.Create(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)

I suspect the only other relevant detail in the message relates to the origin of the error, which is:

> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade.EnsureCreated()

Obviously, the suggestion there is to set the property `NullabilityInfoContextSupport` to `true`. I have searched online for this, and tried but still receive the same error, so either I am doing it wrong, or there's something else going on.

The relevant code is below:

.csproj file:

```
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net8.0-android;net8.0-ios;net8.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
        <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
        <NullabilityInfoContextSupport>true</NullabilityInfoContextSupport>
```

Out of desperation, I also added it to another PropertyGroup which targetted iOS:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net8.0-ios'">
    <CodesignKey>Apple Development: Created via API (Hidden)</CodesignKey>
    <CodesignProvision>VS: WildCard Development</CodesignProvision>
    <NullabilityInfoContextSupport>true</NullabilityInfoContextSupport>
</PropertyGroup>
```

and even on its own:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <NullabilityInfoContextSupport>true</NullabilityInfoContextSupport>
</PropertyGroup>
```

The `OnConfiguring` method of my context:

```
{
    string connectionString = $"Filename={Utilities.Sqlite.GetPath("fire.db")}";
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(connectionString);
}
```

I have exhausted everything I can think of. What can I look at next?

Comment: Mostly for lulz but can you try adding `AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Reflection.NullabilityInfoContext.IsSupported", true);` somewhere as early in the app startup as possible?

Comment: Just tried - added it as the first line in ```CreateMauiApp``` and... the app launches. It goes horribly wrong elsewhere... but not at the first stage any longer! THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Courtesy of [rolfbjarne@github](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/16228#issuecomment-1400850817):

> The workaround seems to be to force the runtime setting for `NullabilityContextInfoSupported` by executing this early on in the process startup (I added it as the first line of the `MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp`):

> ```
> AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Reflection.NullabilityInfoContext.IsSupported", true);
> ```

Though according to the [issue which was created in the linked dicussion](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/17579) the problem should have been fixed. Possibly try upgrading VS and used libraries.

Comment: I still have the current error, and the work around does nothing, Anyone else have any ideas.